# Rank of a joint distribution matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbf P}$$\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}$Suppose I have discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ supported on $\{1,\dots,m\}$ and $\{1,\dots,n\}$ respectively, and WLOG I'll assume $m \geq n$. Let $\P$ be the $m\times n$ matrix with $\P_{ij} = P(X=i, Y=j)$ and $f$ and $g$ are the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. I know $\rank\P = 1 \iff X\perp Y$. In general how does the rank of $\P$ interact with the kinds of dependencies that are possible? I'm also interested in relating more continuous measures of $\P$'s closeness to being rank $1$, like $\frac{d_1}{\sum_i d_i}$ where the $d_i$ are the singular values of $\P$, to the lack of dependence between $X$ and $Y$. I've explored trying to bound $\P - fg^T$ in terms of these quantities as well but to no avail so far.

---

I'd also be interested in exploring the simpler case of $m=n$ and $X\stackrel{\text{d}}= Y$ so $P$ is square, the marginals are the same, and also I'll take $P(X=i,Y=j) = P(X=j, Y=i)$ so $P$ is symmetric. Then $P = Q\Lambda Q^T$ by the spectral theorem but maybe this isn't helpful. Perhaps nonnegative matric factorization provides more insight?

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer you're looking for (so it'll start as a comment), but suppose $\text{rank} \mathbf{P} = k$. Then there exists random variables $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{k}$ supported on $\{1,\dots,m\}$ that are independent of $Y$, and a random variable $\omega$ supported on $\{1,\dots,k\}$ dependent on $Y$ such that:
$$X = \sum_{j=1}^{k} X_{j} \mathbb{1}_{\omega=j}$$ 
For continuous random variables, you could make this the definition of $k$: the minimum number of independent random variables $X_{1},\ldots, X_{k}$ such that there exists this construction of $X$ for some $\omega$.

Comment: @SherwinLott that sounds intriguing, I'd definitely be interested in a longer version

Comment: My claim seemed intuitive to me, haha, but I haven't been able to prove it. I just posted it as [my own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3806254/how-many-corners-of-simplex-intersected-by-hyperplane) and will add a bounty in two days if it's not solved.

Comment: @SherwinLott ok cool, thanks! Hopefully something interesting comes from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware whether there is a relation between the rank of P and any kind of dependency between $X$ and $Y$. But, there is a nice characterization of the dependence between $X$ and $Y$ with the corresponding nonnegative rank.

Let us assume for simplicity that both, $X$ and $Y$ take values in $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ (the case $n \neq m$ is analogous).

Let $Z$ be a random variable taking values in $\{1, \ldots, r\}$. Then $X$, $Y$ are independent conditioned on $Z$, if $P$ can be written as
$$ P(X = i, Y = j) = \sum_{k=1}^{r} P(X=i|Z=k) \cdot P(Y=j|Z=k) \cdot P(Z = k).\quad \quad \quad \quad(1)$$

On the other hand we can define the nonnegative rank of a matrix in the following way: The nonnegative rank is the minimal integer $r$ such that there exists a decomposition
$$ P = \sum_{k=1}^{r} \mathbf{v}_k \cdot \mathbf{w}_k^T $$
where $\mathbf{v}_k, \mathbf{w}_k \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}$. Hence the matrix admits a decomposition into rank-1 matrices generated by nonnegative vectors (instead of general vectors as in the case of the usual rank).

Now the following assertions are equivalent:

(a) $X$ and $Y$ are independent conditioned on $Z$ which takes $r$ values.

(b) $\textrm{nn-rank}(P) = r$.

To show (a) $\Longrightarrow$ (b) just set $(\mathbf{v}_k)_i := P(X=i|Z=k)$ and $(\mathbf{w}_k)_j := P(Y=j|Z=k) \cdot P(Z=k)$ and the independency relation leads to a nn-rank decomposition of rank $r$.

To show (b) $\Longrightarrow$ (a) set
$$P(X=i|Z=k) := \frac{(\mathbf{v}_k)_i}{\Vert \mathbf{v}_k \Vert_1}$$
and
$$P(Y=j|Z=k) := \frac{(\mathbf{w}_k)_j}{\Vert \mathbf{w}_k \Vert_1}$$
Dividing by the the 1-norm guarantees the normalization of the defined probability distributions. Now it only remains to define $P(Z=k)$.
We set
$$P(Z = k) := \Vert \mathbf{v}_k \Vert_1 \cdot \Vert \mathbf{w}_k \Vert_1$$
This definition gives again a probability distribution, since all vectors are nonnegative and
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{r} P(Z=k) = \sum_{k=1}^{r} \Vert \mathbf{v}_k \Vert_1 \cdot \Vert \mathbf{w}_k \Vert_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{r} \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} (\mathbf{v}_k)_i \cdot (\mathbf{w}_k)_j = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} P(X=i, Y=j) = 1$$
Plugging in these definitions into the rank-decomposition yields to the sum (1) which shows the statement.

Comment: this is great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:

*The higher is the rank, the lower the probability that the two variables are almost independent*

In the picture below I plot the empirical cumulative distribution of mutual information between two random variables given the rank of the matrix P, assuming that matrix P has shape 3x4. Obviously, for rank=1 mutual information is always zero. For rank=2 it is almost zero most of the time, but for rank=3 it is almost zero much less frequently.

[image: CDF]

Here's the code to get this result. It is extremely inefficient, as I have to generate random matrices of a given rank until I get a matrix for which all elements are non-negative, so it can be normalized to a 2D probability distribution. This simulaton could be extended to higher ranks if this inefficiency can be overcome in some way, but so far I have no ideas.

```
from time import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import ortho_group  # Requires version 0.18 of scipy

def rand_posdiag_matrix(m, n, rk):
    D = np.zeros((m, n))
    diag = np.zeros(np.min([m, n]))
    diag[:rk] = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, rk)
    np.fill_diagonal(D, diag)
    
    U = ortho_group.rvs(dim=m)
    V = ortho_group.rvs(dim=n)
    return U.dot(D.dot(V.T))
    
def rand_pos_matrix(m, n, rk):
    M = rand_posdiag_matrix(m, n, rk)
    while np.min(M) < 0:
        M = rand_posdiag_matrix(m, n, rk)
    return M / np.sum(M)

def H1D(p):
    return -p.dot(np.log(p))

def MI(p2D):
    pX = np.sum(p2D, axis=0)
    pY = np.sum(p2D, axis=1)
    return H1D(pX) + H1D(pY) - H1D(p2D.flatten())
    
def cdf(x):
    return sorted(x), np.linspace(0, 1, len(x))
    
nTrial = 100
nRank = 3
rezMat = np.zeros((nRank, nTrial))

for iRank in range(nRank):
    for iTrial in range(nTrial):
        t = time()
        
        M = rand_pos_matrix(3, 4, iRank+1)
        rezMat[iRank, iTrial] = MI(M)
        
#         print(iRank, iTrial, time() - t)
        
plt.figure()
for iRank in range(nRank):
    plt.plot(*cdf(rezMat[iRank]), label=str(iRank+1))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: So in general (mutual information) is knowing pdf of one random variable, we would know to some degree pdf of another random variable? Is that what mutual information is telling us?

Comment: thank you, that is definitely the intuition that led me to asking this question in the first place. The more "high frequency" components in $P$, the more complicated the dependencies we'll see. I'm hoping to try to formalize this and get theoretical insight but numerical results are always helpful too!

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER Mutual information tells us by how much our predictive power of one of the variables increases if the other variable is known. So if variables are independent, knowing one of the variables does not help us guess the other one better, so MI is zero. On the other hand side, if the two variables are copies of each other, knowing one is the same as knowing the other, and MI is maximal

Comment: @AleksejsFomins, this makes soo much sense. So its is indeed similar to correlation, if two random variables are correlated, then know the outcome of one helps us predict the outcome of another and if the two random variables are copies, they are fully correlated and correlation coeficient is 1 i.e. maximal.

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER mutual information is equivalent to correlation for linear relationships between varaibles. However, it is much better, because it can handle non-linear relationships as well, since it directly analyses the density of probability-space instead of approximating it by a multivariate gaussian distribution. The downside is that it is hard to calculate it for continuous variables, but there are fancy libraries for it. Definitely a good tool to learn to use :)

Comment: +1 thanks so much you have comprehensively summarized a very good point, so correlation is handling linear relationships while mutual information is handling both linear as well as nonlinear relationships but harder to compute. This gave me lots of intuition on mutual information indeed!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt anything will come out of this. Especially if you are not able to be more specific than "the kinds of dependencies that are possible". Take the most simple example: two Bernoulli variables or a 2x2 matrix. Given the probabilities of $X$ and $Y$ all dependency is contained in a single parameter. Nevertheless, all these joint distributions - except the independent one - have a rank 2 matrix.

To make further progress you should in my opinion:

1. Study simple cases like 2x3 or 3x3
2. Make up your mind what kind of dependency you are really interested in.