# How many Corners of Simplex Intersected by Hyperplane?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, geometry, simplex

There are $K$ linearly independent points on a $N-1$ dimensional simplex:
$$x^{1}, \ldots, x^{K} \in \Delta^{N-1}$$
$$x^{k} = (x^{k}_{1}, \ldots, x^{k}_{N})$$
I would like to prove their exists $K$ "corners" of the span of $x^{1}, \ldots, x^{K}$ on the simplex:
$$y^{1}, \ldots, y^{K} \in \Delta^{N-1}$$

$$\mathcal{A} = \text{span}\left(\left\{ x^{1}, \ldots, x^{K} \right\}\right) \cap \Delta^{N-1}$$

Such that every point in $\mathcal{A}$ is a **convex** combination of $y^{1}, \ldots, y^{K}$.

---

Background: I've been trying to solve [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3640695/rank-of-a-joint-distribution-matrix#comment7830442_3640695) (sorry, the notation doesn't line up perfectly).  The idea is that $x^{k}$ is one of $K$ independent rows of their matrix, and $y^{k}$ is the probability distribution for a new random variable $X^{k}$ independent of $Y$.  We can then construct a new random variable $\omega$ dependent on $Y$ with support $\{1, \ldots, K\}$ such that:

$$X = \sum_{k=1}^{K} X^{k} \mathbb{1}_{\omega=k}$$

by letting the probability distribution of $\omega | Y$ be the appropriate convex weights of the $y^{1}, \ldots, y^{k}$. I think the variance of $\omega$ also gives a good continuous measure for the original question.

---

Attempt: I was trying to come up with an iterative construction where I first include any basis vectors in $\mathcal{A}$, then any linear combination of two basis vectors in $\mathcal{A}$ not spanned by the vectors I've already included, "and so on" until I've constructed $y^{1}, \ldots, y^{K}$. I don't know how to continue in an orderly way that provably constructs the $K$ points (or if this is the simplest approach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for a proof that (among other things)  a planar slice through a solid tetrahedron in three space must be a triangle.

The following is an example where this fails:

Let $K=3, N=4$, let the $K$ linearly independent points in $\mathbb R^4$ be

$$x^1=(1/2,0,1/2,0)\\x^2=(0,1/2,1/2,0)\\x^3=(0,1/2,0,1/2)$$ and let $$x^4=(1/2,0,0,1/2).$$
Let $\mathcal A=\operatorname{span}(\{x^1,x^2,x^3\})\cap \Delta^3$.
Note that  $x^4=x^1-x^2+x^3\in \operatorname{span}(\{x^1,x^2,x^3\})$, that $x^4\in\Delta^3$, and that $\mathcal A$ is the convex hull of $\{x^1,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$, and that
$\mathcal A$ has the four $x^j$ as its extreme points, the sought after "corners".

Comment: +1. Indeed, this leads to a nice little dissection of a regular tetrahedron into two congruent pieces, both sort of like three-D trapezoids, which mate at their square faces to reconstitute the original tetrahedron.  Initially counter-intuitive, but oddly satisfying.  (I first encountered this in a *Mathematical Games* column decades ago, and made a paper model that engaged me longer than I thought it would have.)

Comment: I also like kimchi.

Comment: @BrianTung Thanks!  I found myself making a tetrahedron with my fingers, and noticing that my knuckles could play the role of the $x^j$.  A paper model of the dissection sounds like a fun project.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I guess my lesson here is not to be so presumptuous when generalizing an idea beyond three dimensions.

Comment: I think "presumptuous" is way too strong a word here.  The world  needs guesses; some will turn out wrong, and the process of checking them refines our tool set.